# Salesforce Bulk API Sink Connector creates too many batches

Tags: apache-kafka, salesforce, apache-kafka-connect

I am building a prototype to synch data from MySQL to Salesforce running Kafka in Docker containers on my laptop. I followed [Quick Start for Confluent Platform](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/7.1.2/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html#step-1-download-and-start-cp) to install and run Confluent Platform. To take data from MySQL and send over to Salesforce I am using [Debezium MySQL CDC Source Connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/debezium/debezium-connector-mysql) and [Salesforce Bulk API Connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-salesforce-bulk-api). Everything works fine except that when new updates from MySQL come one by one with a small but bigger than half a second delay the connector creates a batch for each update. So, running the following bash script creates 3 batches in Salesforce:

```bash
for i in $(seq 3); do
    QUERY="UPDATE some_table SET state = 'state_$i' where id = 1;"
    mysql -u user_name -h host_name -e "$QUERY" -p<mysql_password>
    sleep .7
done
```

The problem here is that the Salesforce connector pushes records to Salesforce too often, while there is a limit in Salesforce for the max number of batches per 24 hours - 15,000. To guarantee to stay within this limit I’d like to enforce the connector to buffer updates before pushing them into Salesforce. To archive that I am trying to set `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms` properties. There is a document [Salesforce Bulk API Sink Connector Configuration Properties](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/salesforce-bulk-api/current/sink/configuration_options.html#overriding-default-configuration-properties) which says

> You can override producer-specific properties by using the `confluent.topic.producer.` prefix and consumer-specific properties by using the `confluent.topic.consumer.` prefix.

So my attempt was to put these properties in the salesforce connector config (here I want the connector to buffer records for 10sec or until they reach 1000 bytes):

```
    "confluent.topic.consumer.fetch.max.wait.ms": "10000",
    "confluent.topic.consumer.fetch.min.bytes": "1000"
```

It seems like it has no effect as `fetch.max.wait.ms` stays to be 500ms which is the default value.

So, first I'd like to make sure that I am looking into the right direction trying to use `fetch.min.bytes` and `fetch.max.wait.ms` properties, that they are applicable to the connector at all. And second, how can I set these properties properly?

Comment: The Confluent command topic properties isn't what you should be overriding. Look at the Apache Kafka website for how to set internal producer/consumer configs in Connect (ex `consumer.override.` prefix)

Comment: https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-improvements-in-apache-kafka-2-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @OneCricketeer, the [link](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-improvements-in-apache-kafka-2-3/) you provided helped me to solve the problem. Although I didn't change the `connector.client.config.override.policy` setting for the worker as it is described in the "Connector-level producer/consumer configuration overrides" section, just setting `fetch.max.wait.ms` and `fetch.min.bytes` for the connector was enough. So the final version of the connector's config now looks like:

```
{
  "name": "SalesforceBulkApiSinkConnectorConnector_0",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.salesforce.SalesforceBulkApiSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "topics": "sf_sink",
    "errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name": "sf_sink_dlq",
    "salesforce.instance": "https://<instance>.my.salesforce.com",
    "salesforce.username": "<username>",
    "salesforce.password": "<password>",
    "salesforce.password.token": "<token>",
    "salesforce.object": "KafkaEvent__e",   
    "salesforce.sink.object.operation": "insert",
    "override.event.type": "true",
    "salesforce.use.custom.id.field": "false",
    "behavior.on.api.errors": "log",
    "reporter.result.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "reporter.error.topic.replication.factor": "1",
    "reporter.bootstrap.servers": "broker:29092",
    "consumer.override.fetch.max.wait.ms": "10000",
    "consumer.override.fetch.min.bytes": "5000"
  } 
}
```